# Loading memory address from a textbox

Tags: c#, memory, textbox

I am trying to make a application to let users input a memory address in a textbox.

Input in the textbox is: "0x0060EBDC".

And I want the textbox text to be inserted here:

```
Android.SetMemory(''''TEXTBOXTEXT HERE(0x0060EBDC)'''', userinput2);
```

I got it working for the bytes ("userinput2") but cant get it to work for the memory address.

I dont want it converted or anything. Just raw from textbox to code.

Current code:

> //textbox23 memory
>                   //textbox4 value

```
var value = textBox4.Text;

var value = textBox4.Text;

var array = value
    .Split(',')
    .Select(i => i.Trim().Replace("0x", ""))
    .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i, 16))
    .ToArray();

Android.SetMemory(0x0060EBDC, array);
```

So I want 0x0060EBDC to be replaced with userinputted textbox "0x00100101".

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of your `SetMemory` method seems to be simply a 64 bit unsigned integer (`ulong` in .NET).

You must convert the text of the textbox to a number, so you can use it as a parameter in your method (which you are already doing for your array variable?).

```
ulong address = Convert.ToUInt64(textbox.Text, 16);
Android.SetMemory(address, array);
```

`Convert.ToUInt64` will automatically handle input formats with and without prefixed `0x`/`0X`. If you want to do proper error checking before trying to convert the textbox's value, use the `ulong.TryParse(string, out ulong)` method instead.

But be careful allowing users access to arbitrary memory locations.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Tried it and it gave me "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string." Also, what does 16 stand for?

Comment: I don't know what your string input exactly is, but maybe you have to call `.Trim()` first? Make sure there are no trailing or leading whitespace characters. 16 is the base used for conversion. You are already converting your array variable the same way, so I'm not sure why you have problems doing the same thing for another variable?

Comment: It spits out an error saying Argument 1: Cannot convert from int[] to ulong and Argument 2: cannot convert from bytep[ to string. I am an absolute beginner on this. Thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: Alright, so the method takes an `ulong` (`UInt64`) as its first parameter. My sample code doesn't use `int[]` anywhere, so the error must be on your side. Argument 2 is left as is – if it worked before it must still work.

Comment: Your sample code gave error Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string. Using same method as array produces the Argument errors.

Comment: Then your input is not valid. Strip any characters that are not a hex number or don't input them. You must not use the same textbox as for your other param. Use two textboxes (if you use a single textbox it will complicate matters since you need to extract both parameters)